# Is it possible to pass pointers to a struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I am calling from `main` the function `init_latent_variables` and passing pointer to a struct `sample` of type `SAMPLE`

```
int main(){
    SAMPLE sample;
    sample = read_struct_examples();
    init_latent_variables(&sample);
    return 0;
}

SAMPLE read_struct_examples() {
    SAMPLE sample;        
    sample.examples = (EXAMPLE *) malloc(1*sizeof(EXAMPLE));
    if(!sample.examples) die("Memory error.");
    return(sample); 
}
```

Following is function definition. The memory allocation works fine in this function, but the original variable in `main` remains unchanged.

```
void init_latent_variables(SAMPLE *sample) {
    sample->examples[0].h.h_is = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    if(!sample->examples[0].h.h_is) die("Memory error.");       
}
```

Following are the struct definitions:

```
typedef struct latent_var {
  int *h_is;
} LATENT_VAR;

typedef struct example {
  LATENT_VAR h;
} EXAMPLE;

typedef struct sample {
  EXAMPLE *examples;
} SAMPLE;
```

Am I right in passing a pointer to struct. Is it possible to do so in C?

**UPDATE**: Not sure what was wrong earlier. Clean and recompile seems to work. Thanks and apologies for wasting your time. Already flagged the question so that moderators could delete it.

Comment: C doesn't have "references". You have to call by value.

Comment: The code seems to work to me, how do you see the original value not changed?

Comment: I checked the original value in GDB.

Answer (score 0):

You're dereferenceing `sample->examples` before you allocate it:

```
void init_latent_variables(SAMPLE *sample) {
    sample->examples[0].h.h_is = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    if(!sample->examples[0].h.h_is) die("Memory error.");       
}
```

this should be :

```
void init_latent_variables(SAMPLE *sample, int num_examples) {
    sample->examples = (EXAMPLE *) malloc(sizeof EXAMPLE * num_examples);
    if(!sample->examples) die("Memory error.");   
    sample->examples[0].h.h_is = (int *) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    if(!sample->examples[0].h.h_is) die("Memory error.");       
}
```

Consider using calloc() instead of malloc, or use memset to clear your structs to 0 before using them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to allocate examples member of SAMPLE structure... As I understand it must be an array of objects... And, of course, there are no references in C, only "value" or "pointer".